# Using location.reload on Chrome is not working as it should, using the same code in Firefox works fine

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reload

I am making a Snake game using Javascript and checking if the user has touched the borders, if he has than it's gameover and a game over function is called which shows a confirm box with it's content based on the language of the html file because i have 2 html files: one for French and one for English.

```
this.alert = alert;

this.gameOver = function() {
    const langCheck = document.getElementById("html").lang;
    if (langCheck === "fr") {
      alert = confirm("\t\tPerdu!\n\n Votre longueur était: " + this.eaten);
    } else {
      alert = confirm(
        "\t\tGame Over!\n\n Your snake length was: " + this.eaten
      );
    }
    console.log(alert);

    if (alert === true) {
      document.location.reload(true);
    } else {
      document.location.reload(true);
    }
  };
```

In chrome when i click either Ok or Cancel the confirm box just reopens instantly and it doesn't reload (Edit: Forgot to mention but the page just hangs after clicking ok) even though console logging alert it returns true. So why isn't this working on Chrome when on Firefox it's working perfectly?

I tried many different location.reload i saw when i researched on it like `window.location.reload()` but it's the exact same.

I'm stuck here because as i said in Firefox it works flawlessly and that's where i initially tested when i programmed the game but when i finished i decided to take a look if on Chrome it worked, that's when i found out.

Comment: try history.go(0) instead, or just wrap the code in a timeout setTimeout(function(){
  window.location.reload();
});, Normally chrome is ok with just  window.location.reload();

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `location.reload()` you can try (code taken from another solution online)

```js
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.reload();
},100);
```

Also considering you're running the same code if `alert === true` and if it's not true, I would just get rid of the if/else and run the code directly (if that's what you intend to do)

Answer (score 0):

`document.location.reload(true);` will be ok for Google chrome you can check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dfy0Lgcv/) example here.

You have other alternatives also

1. `setTimeout(function(){ window.location.reload(); });`
2. `window.location.reload();`

A short note :

```
if (alert === true) {
      document.location.reload(true);
    } else {
      document.location.reload(true);
    }
```

Irrespective of result you are doing the same operation here, So you can simplify the code like below. The `if else` is not at all needed there.

```
 document.location.reload(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
window.location.reload(false);
```